# Array dependencies and recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, pseudocode

I have 5 arrays (A, B, C, D, E) and they depend on each other in the following way:

```
E depends on A.
B depends on A, C, D.
A depends on B, C.
C depends on E.
```

I start with the input `(array, value)` and for each remaining array I want to assign `value+1` if it is a dependent of my given array. The same logic applies to the others. Each dependent array must be set only the first time it is encountered. For example, for `(A,1)`:

```
A 1
B 2
C 2
D 3
E 3
```

I wanted to create a dictionary and then iterate through my conditions, but it doesn't sound like a recursion.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    private static final Map<String, List<String>> DEPENDENT_MAP;
    static {
        Map<String, List<String>> localMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        localMap.put ("E", Arrays.asList ("A"));
        localMap.put ("B", Arrays.asList ("A", "C", "D"));
        localMap.put ("A", Arrays.asList ("B", "C"));
        localMap.put ("C", Arrays.asList ("E"));
        DEPENDENT_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap (localMap);
    }

    private static void setValue (String column, int value) {
        System.out.println (column + "->" + value);
    }

    private static void setDependentValues (String column, int value) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setDependentValues ("A", 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this in `java` or `python`? Also, would you please post the code you have so far?

Comment: Seems like you can do this with a breadth-first graph traversal...

Comment: @Aziz Java, sorry! I posted the code so far.